# smarty {cycle}, and three values

Tags: smarty

how use {cycle} with three values?
Whats wrong with this code:

```
<table>
   <tr bgcolor="{cycle values='#aaaaaa,#bbbbbb'}">
      <td bgcolor="{cycle values='#1112233,#334455'}">value</td>
      <td bgcolor="{cycle values='#998811,#334466'}">value1</td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I assume the above code is in a looping construct, right? Mind posting that part too, assuming it is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to give them unique names:

```
{cycle name='color1' values='#aaaaaa,#bbbbbb'}
{cycle name='color2' values='#1112233,#334455'}
{cycle name='color3' values='#998811,#334466'}
```